# Magnific-popup with Google InfoBox and titleSrc

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, magnific-popup, domready

With this code below I can not get, below the image popup, the title !

I do not know what i'm doing wrong !!!

If I remove 'titleSrc : 'data-title'' everything works fine ;))

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(infobox, "domready", function () {
$('.pop').on('click', function () {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items : {
            src : $(this).data('lg'),
        },
        type : 'image',
        image : {
            titleSrc : 'data-title' // My data-title in the A HREF
        }
    });
});
```

});

Thanks for your help

**UPDATED**

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(infobox, "domready", function () {
$('.pop').on('click', function () {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items : {
            src : $(this).data('lg')
        },
        type : 'image',
        image : {
            titleSrc : $(this).data('title')
        }
    });
});
```

});

Even if I put titleSrc : 'TEST'

Comment: I believe if you have an attribute on your HTML that is 'data-title', you have to refer to it like this with jQuery: `titleSrc : $(this).data('dataTitle')`  This is from the example given in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I tried but it does not work !

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the end of this line here, which will cause problems in IE: `src : $(this).data('lg'),`

Comment: can you also update your question to show us the code you tried with my suggestion?

Comment: Update done on my question

Comment: My original comment was a mistake, sorry.  What does your HTML look like that contains the 'data-lg' and 'data-title' values?

Comment: <a class="pop lgShow" href="javascript:void(0)" data-title="Mather Point Grand Canyon National Park, Arizona" data-lg="../img/latlon/lg/0726_mather_point_grand_canyon_national_park_arizona.jpg">